# Windows Clustering and SQL Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2016, storage

I am new to Clustering and Availability groups.  I am creating a 4 node Windows 2012 Cluster with SQL 2016 enterprise.  SQL will not be clustered we are just using the availability group option.  The cluster is setup like: 3 servers on one site and 1 server offsite.  Our goal is to have multiple databases on the servers Server 1 would be primary for availability group 1 and server 2 would be primary for availability group 2.  Server 3 and 4 would be primary failover availability groups as well as server 1 being a failover for server 2 and server 2 being a failover for server 1.  Server 4 would also be the offsite DR server.

I have the windows cluster setup to have the Quorum drive as a file share that all 4 servers can get too.  One of the databases on the servers will need access to the file system for import and export of csv, xls, etc. files.

How can all 4 servers have access to this drive, when I have one server in a different location on a different subnet?

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> How can all 4 servers have access to this drive, when I have one server in a different location on a different subnet?

Get really friendly with your network and security teams. Ask them, politely if need be, to create a file share for that folder and allow your service accounts access to said file share.

Other than the service account, this really doesn't have any involvement with SQL Server.